# Loading CSV files using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, import

This script works with older version of QGIS but not the latest one.

What is wrong with this script?

I do not think the space in the directory name is the cause.

```
import os.path, glob

from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

layers=[]

for file in glob.glob('C://Back Up/t1/*.txt'): 
  uri = "file:///" + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&useHeader=no&crs=epsg:4326" % (",","field_3","field_2") #(Delimeter, XField, YField) #1st column in file is column 1

  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'Y') #these order of columns go: 0, 1, 2 etc
  vlayer.setFieldAlias(2,'X')
  layers.append(vlayer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages or what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your txt file ?

Comment: Maybe try glob.glob(r'C:\Back Up\t1\*.txt') instead backslashes

Comment: 1,41.4984009681843, -95.140816841121, None, None, None, None, 
2,41.4984009681843, -95.140813098166, None, None, None, None, 
3,41.4984009681843, -95.1408093789465, None, None, None, None, 
4,41.4984009681843, -95.1408068878986, None, None, None, None, 
5,41.4984009681843, -95.1408052062334, None, None, None, None, 
6,41.4984009681843, -95.140804085402, None, None, None, None,

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.path.normpath in case forward slashes and backslashes are mixed in the path but your main problem seems that you try to run the code in the python console and not the console editor. For single lines the console is ok but for multi line code snippets you have to use the console editor:
[image]

Comment: THis is the error I am getting:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1

Comment: File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
  File "<input>", line 1
    import os.path, glob
                        ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: You have to run the code in the console editor for multi line code snippets